# App installed in Program files freezes when is used by a user without admin permissions

Tags: windows-7, admin

Excuse me for my poor english.

I have an application running on Windows 2000 and XP. The application runs too without problems in Vista/Seven, but only works in case of user be administrator, else the application freezes when:

1- I save log files in a subfolder of Program files.

2- Run a update routine than download files from a server in Program files.

3- I suppose on another taks in Program files for only Admins...**

How I can do the app running for any user, with any permissions? Is needed install for each user? Is needed install in another path?

When the application freezes not throw an error, only is collapsed and is needed close with task manager.

Regards and many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is number 1, saving log files under Program Files.

The place where application data is supposed to be saved since Windows XP is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data or C:\Documents and Settings\ (individual user) \Application Data

The Windows XP environment variable %ALLUSERSPROFILE% points to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users

The Windows XP environment variable %APPDATA% points to C:\Documents and Settings\ (individual user) \Application Data

Your application might be doing other administrative only tasks.

The best way to find out is first, move your log files to a application specific folder under Application Data.  Then run your application as a user and see where it stops or hangs up.  You may have to write status messages to a separate log file to narrow down within your code where it's freezing.